# Issues with hibernation

Tags: linux-mint, hibernate

I decided to switch to linux word with my new Laptop.
I picked up Linux Mit 18.2 64 bits and installed it.

The problem I am facing is that every time I hibernate my computer It gets stuck.

Some times It is during the restart process, other times between the phase  the laptop is saving the current session.

Comment: Is the hibernation issue persistent while the laptop is connected to charger?

Comment: How much RAM does your laptop have and what size is the swap partition? Swap should be double, but at least slightly more than RAM to make hibernation work

Comment: @AbhikBose :Yes it is persistant even when it is connected to charger

Comment: @xanoetus: I have 8 GB of ram and my swap memory is of size 8GB also ( I used swapon -s)